# How do I retrieve a specific row of data from a testng dataprovider?

Tags: java, testng

I have a data provider like below:

```
@DataProvider(name = "therapistToDoList") public static Object[][] data(){
        return new Object[][]{
                {"06012017", "Low", "This is a low task description added via automation for therapist/admin."},
                {"06012017", "Medium", "This is medium task description added via automation for therapist/admin."},
                {"06012017", "High", "This is high task description added via automation for therapist/admin."},
        };
    }
```

How do I run my test case using this data provider, but only for one specific row and not all of them?

Is that even possible with the testng dataprovider?

Comment: Why don't you comment or delete these lines, if you don't use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways may be- you keep a counter and check if you have reached your target data and then do your task.

**Demo code:**

```
public class TestDemo {
        public static int count = 0;


        DataProvider(name = "therapistToDoList") public static Object[][] data(){
            return new Object[][]{
               {"06012017", "Low", "This is a low task description added via automation for therapist/admin."},
               {"06012017", "Medium", "This is medium task description added via automation for therapist/admin."},
               {"06012017", "High", "This is high task description added via automation for therapist/admin."},
            };
       }

       @Test(dataProvider = "therapistToDoList")
       public void testWithSpecificDataFromDataProvider(String a, String b, String c) {
           count++;
          if(count == 2){//let's say you are interest in 2nd data/row
          System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
          break;
          }
       }

}
```

Comment: your solution was performing my intended step, which was executing the test with just 1 row of the dataprovider,  however the test result was showing that the test was executed thrice, which was not so good to see as I wanted the test to run only once with a specific row.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the tool you should stick to the ideology that it follows. DataProviders are there to run the test for each data row.

If you need some different data - then create a different DataProvider. It could invoke the initial one and filter the values from there. Or even better - there could be a small DataProvider and then a larger one that includes values from the smaller one and adds its own rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working sample that accepts a particular row as a choice from the TestNG suite xml file (or) via the JVM argument and then the data provider's rows get filtered accordingly.

```
public class FilteredDataProviderExample {

    @Test (dataProvider = "therapistToDoList")
    public void testWithSpecificDataFromDataProvider(String a, String b, String c) {
        Assert.assertNotNull(a);
        Assert.assertNotNull(b);
        Assert.assertNotNull(c);
    }

    @DataProvider (name = "therapistToDoList")
    public static Object[][] data(ITestContext ctx) {
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
            {"06012017", "Low", "This is a low task description added via automation for therapist/admin."},
            {"06012017", "Medium", "This is medium task description added via automation for therapist/admin."},
            {"06012017", "High", "This is high task description added via automation for therapist/admin."},
        };
        return filterData(data, ctx.getCurrentXmlTest());
    }

    private static Object[][] filterData(Object[][] data, XmlTest xmlTest) {
        //What if the value was given as a JVM argument.
        int rowFromJVM = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("row", "-1"));
        if (rowFromJVM > 0 && rowFromJVM < data.length) {
            return new Object[][] {
                data[rowFromJVM]
            };
        }
        int row = - 1;
        //Lets check if there was any filtering defined either at the <test> level or at the
        //<suite> level.
        if (xmlTest.getAllParameters().containsKey("row")) {
            row = Integer.parseInt(xmlTest.getParameter("row"));
        }
        if (row > 0 && row < data.length) {
            return new Object[][] {
                data[row]
            };
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```